# Problemas usando lookAt en openGL

Tags: c++, opengl

Apenas estoy comenzando a utilizar OpenGL. Estoy intentando cambiar los parámetros de los vectores eye y view correspondientes a la función lookAt cada que aprieto una tecla. El fragmento de código en donde intento hacerlo es el siguiente:

```
int main(){
mainWindow = Window(800, 600);
mainWindow.Initialise();

//CreateObject();
CrearCubo();
cubo->bindVAO();
CreateShaders();

GLuint uniformProjection = 0;
GLuint uniformModel = 0;
GLuint uniformView = 0;

glm::mat4 projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(60.0f) , mainWindow.getBufferWidth() / mainWindow.getBufferHeight(), 0.1f, 100.0f);

//Loop mientras no se cierra la ventana
while (!mainWindow.getShouldClose())
{
    //Recibir eventos del usuario
    glfwPollEvents();

    glm::mat4 view = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(mainWindow.ejeX , mainWindow.ejeY, mainWindow.ejeZ),
                                 glm::vec3(mainWindow.viewX, mainWindow.viewY, mainWindow.viewZ),
                                 glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));

    //Limpiar la ventana
    glClearColor(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); //Se agrega limpiar el buffer de profundidad

    shaderList[0].useShader();

    uniformModel = shaderList[0].getModelLoaction();

    uniformProjection = shaderList[0].getProjectLocation();
    uniformView = shaderList[0].getViewLocation();

    //model = glm::mat4(1.0);
    glm::mat4 model(1.0);
    model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -2.5f));


    glUniformMatrix4fv(uniformModel, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));//FALSE ES PARA QUE NO SEA TRANSPUESTA
    glUniformMatrix4fv(uniformProjection, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projection));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(uniformView, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view));

    meshList[0]->RenderMesh();

    glUseProgram(0);
    mainWindow.swapBuffers();
}
return 0;}
```

Ya verifiqué que los valores de ejeX, ejeY, ejeZ, viewX, viewY y viewZ cambien. Además, algunos compañeros utilizaron el mismo código en Windows y les funcionó sin problema, yo estoy usando Mac.